# login error message

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am trying to create a login error message using html, css, and javascript for a login page.  When somebody unsuccessfully logs into a page, I want a message to display saying that their login was unsuccessful.  I have had several ideas, but I am unsure of how to implement this.  One of my ideas in psuedocode is like...

```
var counter = 0;
if(login fails) {
counter++; }
if( counter > 0) {
var errorTag = document.createElement("div");   //display error message
errorTag.innerHTML = "<p>THIS IS AN ERROR</p>";
}
```

I'm not sure how you would implement the login failing as an event.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're not going to actually validate the username and password from within the user's browser, right?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the login failing on the server side. Have the login form submit to a server-side script that authenticates it. If it fails, send the user back to the login page and display an error. If it succeeds, allow the user forward.

There really is no secure way to authenticate a user with just JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to submit the form, through SSL `https` and let whatever login system you have on the server give the reply.